# How to correctly get an element from an array in swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, swift3

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game with player vs computer using swift 3 and I have found that looping through an array is quite different to other languages. I am trying to pick the position (index) of the ones that equal to 0 (available). The gameState represents the spaces on the board from 0-8 (9 spaces) as an array of 0's. Say if the gameState looks like game board positions : [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] then I want it to check for the next available space which would be gameState[3].

```
            for (position,element) in gameState.enumerated() {
                if gameState[element] == 0 && activeComp {
                    takeSpace = gameState[position] + 1
                    print("in gameState[element] is: ", gameState[element])
                    print("in place gameState[position] is: ", gameState[position], "game board positions :", gameState )
                    activeComp = false
                }
                print(position, element, gameState[element])
            }
```

The output of the above code looks something like:

0 1 2

in gameState[element] is:  0
in place gameState[position] is:  2 game board positions : [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

1 2 0

2 0 1

3 0 1

4 0 1

5 0 1

6 0 1

7 0 1

8 0 1

It prints out the position and elements correctly, but as soon as I want to get gameState[element] using the for loop it prints out something alien.

Comment: just because your game looks like an array / matrix there is no need to represent it as one. You might want to move away from an array where columns and rows are mixed to a more clear and straight-forward data-structure.

Comment: `position` is the current index in the enumeration and `element` the array element at that position. You probably want to test `if gameState[position] == 0` or just if `if element == 0` ... – `gameState[element]` would be `gameState[gameState[position]]` and does not make much sense.

Comment: Probably defining an enum for game states would be a good first step.

Comment: @MartinR I am trying to get the value of the index by using `gameState[element]` and see if that index (`position`) is equal to `0` but it is not working and it's doing something else. If I was to use `if gameState[position] == 0` then it will just check if the index of `gameState` is equal to `0` which will always be true.

Comment: Update: Thank you @MartinR you were right. I needed to check `if element == 0` and update `takeSpace = position + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Thank you @MartinR you were right. I needed to check if element == 0 and update takeSpace = position + 1

There was no need for me to use `gameState[element]` rather I should have just been checking if `element == 0` itself since it is looping in `gameState` already. Likewise when I was updating the available space that I wanted to take, I should have been using `position + 1` rather than `gameState[position] + 1`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not subscripting your array correctly. It looks like you made a typo and accidentally indexed using the value of the array. So, instead of:

```
 for (position,element) in gameState.enumerated() {
            if gameState[element] == 0 && activeComp {
```

You would need:

```
 for (position,element) in gameState.enumerated() {
            if gameState[position] == 0 && activeComp {
```

Comment: `gameState[position]` is actually the same as `element`.

Comment: gameState[position] is different to element, element is the value, position is the index. My issue is that I am trying to get the value of the index by using gameState[element] and see if that index (position) is available (0) but it is not working and it's doing something else. If I was to use if gameState[position] == 0 then it will just check if the index of gameState is equal to 0 which will always be true.